# Replace MyISAM files without stopping Mysql

Tags: mysql

I've got a bunch of MyISAM files (MYD, MYI, FRM) in the mysql directory and newer versions of them in another directory. How can I replace "old" ones with "newer" without stopping the mysql server?

Upd: this question is answered over here: https://serverfault.com/questions/340823/replace-myisam-files-without-stopping-mysql

Answer (score 1):

1) Backup the original files (for safety reasons)

2) Replace the old files with the new ones (frm,MYI and MYD) in the mysql data folder. You should copy them in a temp folder on the same hdd/mount/partition before moving them into the data folder, so that the copy process is finished quickly.

3) Execute 'flush tables' on the database.

Now you should have the new data running.

Comment: Are you sure I can do this with mysql server running? What if the server begins writing to disc while the files are being copied?

Comment: You should copy the files to a temp folder on the same partition before, so that a move will only take a few ms. This is not a 100% safe! Operations on this table during move may fail. This is not that bad for read operations, for write operations this may be delicate. But i don't know any other alternative without stopping the server. If you have a table with lots of write opertaions per second, you shouldn't do that. I use this method very often and it works well, but in my setup there are mainly read operations and just a few writes (less than 100 per hour).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way is to work with the actual SQL data, not with the files where they are stored. So:

- put the "new" files in a directory in another server, restart mysql, make SQL dumps of the databases that you need
- import the SQL dumps into your "main" server. Depending on which data is there / is not there you will either be able to import it directly or you'll need to import them into other databases and then rename them to actual names.

Answer (score 0):

This works for copying tables out of the db folder, not sure if it lets you go the other direction:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlhotcopy.html